# Retargeting animation from BVH to FBX

Tags: python, animation, .fbx, motion-capture, bvh

I have an FBX file containing a rigged 3D mesh with its armature, and a BVH file containing animation data for the exact same armature (same skeleton topology and bones names). I import both files in my scene and then I created a small script (see below) to retarget the keyframes from the BVH armature to the FBX one. The script seems to run fine but the orientation of the bones looks wrong and the animation on the FBX looks nothing like the one in the BVH.

I'm thinking the issue may be because the BVH file (source) does not have a proper rest pose while the FBX file (target) has an A pose as rest pose? (see screenshots below)

I have tried to change the rest pose of the BVH to match the rest pose of the FBX and it seems results were better and somewhat matching between the two armatures. That said it's kinda cumbersome and inaccurate to recreate the rest pose manually. I'm not exactly sure how to workaround this and would appreciate any recommendation.

After importing both files, before retargeting:
[image]

After retargeting:
[image]

Rest poses:
[image]

Script:

```py
import bpy

# Bones
# bpy.data.armatures['french_speaker_oration'].bones
# bpy.data.armatures['Solving'].bones

# Get scene and objects data
scene = bpy.context.scene
source_pose = bpy.data.objects['french_speaker_oration'].pose #BVH file
target_pose = bpy.data.objects['Solving'].pose #FBX file
frame_range = bpy.data.actions['french_speaker_oration'].frame_range


#for f in range(int(frame_range[0]), int(frame_range[1])+1):
for frame in range(int(frame_range[0]), 250):
    scene.frame_set(frame)
    for bone in source_pose.bones:
        # Retarget location of the hips
        if bone == "Hips":
            target_pose.bones[bone.name].location.x = source_pose.bones[bone.name].location.x
            target_pose.bones[bone.name].location.y = source_pose.bones[bone.name].location.y
            target_pose.bones[bone.name].location.z = source_pose.bones[bone.name].location.z
            
            # Create keyframe
            target_pose.bones[bone.name].keyframe_insert('location', frame=frame)

        # Retarget rotation
        target_pose.bones[bone.name].rotation_mode = source_pose.bones[bone.name].rotation_mode
        target_pose.bones[bone.name].rotation_euler.x = source_pose.bones[bone.name].rotation_euler.x
        target_pose.bones[bone.name].rotation_euler.y = source_pose.bones[bone.name].rotation_euler.y
        target_pose.bones[bone.name].rotation_euler.z = source_pose.bones[bone.name].rotation_euler.z

        # Create keyframe        
        target_pose.bones[bone.name].keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', frame=frame)
```

Comment: Did u magaged to do it?

Comment: Nop I did not...